# What are the probabilities of getting a "Straight flush" in a poker game?

Tags: card-games

I'm not a pretty much fun of Poker, but I'd like to study that game.

What are the probabilities of getting a Straight flush in a [Poker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker) game considering this factors?

---

Number of players

How are cards dealt

Who is the first player

Comment: very weak actually :)

Comment: What kind of poker? Texas Hold-em? Seven-card stud? Five-card draw? Etc? Or maybe that is what you mean by "how are cards dealt". Also, do you want to factor in behavior? For instance, in Hold-em, if player A's down cards are 2,3 hearts, they would likely fold right off. Yet there's a chance they could have followed it out to a straight flush. These kinds of considerations make the question intractable. That's why most poker calculations stick to a random hand of five cards.

Comment: Try the book, mathematics of poker by bill chen. Decent read.

Comment: Since it's revived, want to add this link: [List of poker hand | Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands#Straight_flush).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are dealt five cards, there are $4\times10 =40$ possible straight flushes ($4\times 9 =36$ if you exclude royal flushes) out of the ${52 \choose 5}= 2598960$ possible hands.  So the probability is $\dfrac{40}{2598960} = \dfrac{1}{64974} \approx 0.00001539\ldots$.

The probability will increase if you can have more than five cards to choose from.  The probability that somebody will have a straight flush will increase if the number of players increases.  It may reduce if you might drop out of the betting before seeing all five cards.